# Do not display python OpenCV error

Tags: python, opencv, error-handling

I am using OpenCV with python, and more specifically the `findTransformECC` fonction of `cv2` to perform image registration. This function can throw errors if the algorithm does not converge. I catch the error with a simple `try ... except` instruction, and I handle the error. However the OpenCV error message is still displayed in my terminal, and I would like to hide it. How should I do?

Here is a simple exemple

```
try:
    cc, warp_matrix = cv2.findTransformECC(img1, img2, warp_matrix)
except cv2.error:
    cc = 15;
    print("An error occured but it does not matter")
```

If the `findTrnaformECC` function throws am error my program correctly outputs my custom error message (`An error occured but it does not matter`) but ALSO the OpenCV error (`OpenCV Error: Iterations do not converge (The algorithm stopped before its convergence. The correlation is going to be minimized. Images may be uncorrelated or non-overlapped) in findTransformECC, file /home/travis/miniconda/conda-bld/conda_1485299288502/work/opencv-3.2.0/modules/video/src/ecc.cpp, line 530`) and I would like to prevent that.

Comment: The error is written to `stderr`. So you can just [redirect `stderr`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6735958/5008845). Or you can tell [opencv to suppress the output](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17575610/5008845), but I'm not aware if there is the Python binding for the `cv::redirectError` function

Comment: this seems great but redirecting the standard error did not do anything...

Comment: Looks like this has been fixed in a later version of OpenCV: with v4.5.3.56, the above approach using `except cv2.error:` is sufficient to catch the exception and the additional output is not written to stderr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirecting `stderr` did not seem to work but it gave me the idea to redirect it from the command-line which works pretty well (on Unix based systems)

```
python myscript.py 2> /dev/null
```

However this will hide all other errors that should be display on `stderr`. This is not a matter for my precise application but it could be.