# How to stop OpenCV error message from printing in Python

Tags: python, opencv

Same as [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567808/how-to-suppress-opencv-error-message/17575610#17575610), except for Python, not C++.

I have an error message in OpenCV that is printing even if I do an except catch around it.

The [solution to the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17575610/5049813) recommends using a redirect function, but [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919314/do-not-display-python-opencv-error#comment74879338_43919314) suggests that function does not exist in Python for OpenCV.

How can I stop an OpenCV error message from printing while still allowing me to print exactly what I want?

Comment: @Prateek What should I do if I have the exact same problem as someone else, it is just in another language? I think I've included enough detail here for someone to solve the problem, and my research (found via the other question) does not work in my case. (Also, thank you for the explanation!)

Comment: Please check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
You should consider rewriting selective content(comment, solution etc. ) from another question here,
users wont have to look into other question for all details. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Prateek IMHO this is a well stated question that shows research effort being done, and which to my knowledge does not have a solution that would satisfy OP's requirements (only removing the OpenCV error messages that by default go to `stderr`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of writing this answer (OpenCV 3.4.1 being the last released version), there is no way to just filter just the output of the default error handler (that I can think of), nor is there a way to change the error handler.

However, your question got me thinking -- in the **highgui** module, we already have several functions that let us set Python callbacks for mouse, trackbar and button events, so we could take inspiration from that code and patch this new functionality in.

Let's work with version 3.4.1. The file of interest is [`modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4.1/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp). We will begin by taking inspiration from functions [`OnMouse`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4.1/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp#L1538) and [`pycvSetMouseCallback`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4.1/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp#L1556).

Let's make the Python error handler have a signature matching the [C++ error handler](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4.1/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp#L168):

```
error_handler([int]status, [str]func_name, [str]err_msg, [str]file_name, [int]line, [obj]userdata) -> None
```

Let's also add support to reset to the default error handler -- something the `highgui` functions don't yet do.

First of all, we'll need a static error handler function, which will marshal arguments from C++ to Python, and call the appropriate Python function to handle the error. Just like the functions we're taking inspiration from, we'll use the user data parameter to hold a tuple consisting of a function object along with optional Python user data).

```
static int OnError(int status, const char *func_name, const char *err_msg, const char *file_name, int line, void *userdata)
{
    PyGILState_STATE gstate;
    gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();

    PyObject *o = (PyObject*)userdata;
    PyObject *args = Py_BuildValue("isssiO", status, func_name, err_msg, file_name, line, PyTuple_GetItem(o, 1));

    PyObject *r = PyObject_Call(PyTuple_GetItem(o, 0), args, NULL);
    if (r == NULL) {
        PyErr_Print();
    } else {
        Py_DECREF(r);
    }

    Py_DECREF(args);
    PyGILState_Release(gstate);

    return 0; // The return value isn't used
}
```

Next, we'll need to write the function to implement the binding between Python and C++. However, due to my [suspicions of potential memory leaks](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/11206) in the functions we're taking inspiration from, we'll make some additions to fix that -- we'll keep track of the most recent user data object and dereference it as necessary.

```
// Keep track of the previous handler parameter, so we can decref it when no longer used
static PyObject* last_on_error_param = NULL;

static PyObject *pycvRedirectError(PyObject*, PyObject *args, PyObject *kw)
{
    const char *keywords[] = { "on_error", "param", NULL };
    PyObject *on_error;
    PyObject *param = NULL;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kw, "O|O", (char**)keywords, &on_error, &param))
        return NULL;

    if ((on_error != Py_None) && !PyCallable_Check(on_error))  {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "on_error must be callable");
        return NULL;
    }
    if (param == NULL) {
        param = Py_None;
    }

    if (last_on_error_param) {
        Py_DECREF(last_on_error_param);
        last_on_error_param = NULL;
    }

    if (on_error == Py_None) {
        ERRWRAP2(redirectError(NULL));        
    } else {
        last_on_error_param = Py_BuildValue("OO", on_error, param);
        ERRWRAP2(redirectError(OnError, last_on_error_param));
    }
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

Finally, we have to register our ["special method"](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4.1/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp#L1684). Unlike the functions we took inspiration from we don't depend on some GUI and we want this to be always available, so we'll modify the code to look as follows:

```
static PyMethodDef special_methods[] = {
  {"redirectError", (PyCFunction)pycvRedirectError, METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS, "redirectError(onError [, param]) -> None"},
#ifdef HAVE_OPENCV_HIGHGUI
  {"createTrackbar", pycvCreateTrackbar, METH_VARARGS, "createTrackbar(trackbarName, windowName, value, count, onChange) -> None"},
  {"createButton", (PyCFunction)pycvCreateButton, METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS, "createButton(buttonName, onChange [, userData, buttonType, initialButtonState]) -> None"},
  {"setMouseCallback", (PyCFunction)pycvSetMouseCallback, METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS, "setMouseCallback(windowName, onMouse [, param]) -> None"},
#endif
  {NULL, NULL},
};
```

Now we can rebuild OpenCV, install it and test it out. I wrote the following script to demonstrate the functionality:

```
import cv2

def verbose_error_handler(status, func_name, err_msg, file_name, line, userdata):
    print "Status = %d" % status
    print "Function = %s" % func_name
    print "Message = %s" % err_msg
    print "Location = %s(%d)" % (file_name, line)
    print "User data = %r" % userdata

def silent_error_handler(status, func_name, err_msg, file_name, line, userdata):
    pass


print "** Default handler"
try:
    cv2.imshow("", None) # This causes an assert
except cv2.error as e:
    pass

print "** Using verbose handler"
cv2.redirectError(verbose_error_handler, 42)
try:
    cv2.imshow("", None) # This causes an assert
except cv2.error as e:
    pass

print "** Using silent handler"
cv2.redirectError(silent_error_handler)
try:
    cv2.imshow("", None) # This causes an assert
except cv2.error as e:
    pass

print "** Back to default handler"
cv2.redirectError(None)
try:
    cv2.imshow("", None) # This causes an assert
except cv2.error as e:
    pass
```

With my patched version of OpenCV (based on the above instructions), I get the following output on my console:

```
** Default handler
OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in cv::imshow, file F:\GitHub\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 364
** Using verbose handler
Status = -215
Function = cv::imshow
Message = size.width>0 && size.height>0
Location = F:\GitHub\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp(364)
User data = 42
** Using silent handler
** Back to default handler
OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in cv::imshow, file F:\GitHub\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 364
```

---

One of my thoughts just as I began writing this answer was that since the [default error handler](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/fed22f2f5c17f28b07e56694825beb94f6574bcc/modules/core/src/system.cpp#L888) uses the following formatting string to output all of those messages to `stderr`

```
"OpenCV(%s) Error: %s (%s) in %s, file %s, line %d"
```

we could perhaps hook the `stderr` stream, and filter out any lines that begin with the constant prefix. Alas, I was not able to achieve this. Perhaps someone else can?

---

Edit: Patched merged into `opencv:master` with some minor modifications (mainly we got rid of the user data parameter, since it's unnecessary in Python).

Comment: I'll see if I can push this to the main OpenCV repo, then this would become a standard feature in future releases.

Comment: Current [pull request](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/11207) for the patch.

Answer (score 3):

The suggested answer didn't work for me - I never saw the callback called. However you *can* control OpenCV logging using environment variables [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67417220).

I assume the environment variables are read once at startup so best to set it before importing.

If you want all messages gone you can use this

```py
os.environ["OPENCV_LOG_LEVEL"]="SILENT"
import cv2
```

Or just to suppress errors (and lower):

```py
os.environ["OPENCV_LOG_LEVEL"]="FATAL"
import cv2
```

See [OpenCV log level definitions](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/68d15fc62edad980f1ffa15ee478438335f39cc3/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/utils/logger.defines.hpp) for other values.

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: @IntegrateThis - care to elaborate - in what way did it fail - what platform, version etc,..?