# pdb post mortem debugger finishes itself

Tags: python, opencv, pdb

I am trying to debug a piece of code that unexpectedly crashes on one of `cv2.resize` calls because of some exception raised in C code. For some reason if I try to run it as `python -m pdb file.py` I get `"Post mortem debugger finished"` message, and therefore can not enter debugging session, since the current line is set to the script's entry point again. Any tips on how to catch this error in the debugger? I guess opencv python wrapper processes errors incorrectly and crashes the whole process instead of raising a python exception. `ipdb` also crashes with some sort of `not self._running` assertion error and messes up the whole terminal session for some reason: a lot of symbols such as newline symbol are not processed properly and `clear` does not help.

The opencv error is `OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (ssize.width > 0 && ssize.height > 0) in resize, file /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp, line 4044`. [This is](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp#L4044) the line in opencv sources, it calls `CV_Assert()`, no idea how it works. I found a line in python code that causes it, I print sizes of images before running resize and they all are of reasonable sizes.

**UPD**: I found an `ValueError: signal only works in main thread` error in logs, so the issue is that this is a C exception in a different thread.

Comment: What version of OpenCV on which platform? Can you create a [mcve] that reproduces it?

Comment: @DanMašek it is CentOS with opencv 3.4.0 and Python 3.6.4. I also wish I could provide a reproducible example, but the error appears somewhere in the body of another poorly written library :) my question is more of a "how to run pdb on false assertions in c code" rather then  "fix my code please" :)

Comment: Oh, I see :) | Hmm, update. That assert causes `cv::Exception` and the wrappers translate those. It would happen if the source image is empty. | Btw, even if you catch the exception, OpenCV will still print the message to stderr (right now the only way to stop that with stable release is [patching OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49604578/3962537))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An issue was indeed caused by image being of width zero, but output was obscured by output from other threads because processing was performed in a pool of workers. A solution was to somehow make that processing code execute in the main thread, and then pdb started debugging session and I was able to figure out the issue.