# How to enable logging for OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I'd like to get the logs out of OpenCV, in particular those from CV_LOG_WARNING calls but I haven't been able to find if there is an environment variable I can set or if there is a setting in the CMakeLists file that will enable this is I build OpenCV from source.

Setup:
OpenCV 4
Cross compiling on Ubuntu 16.04 for an Arm based hardware platform

How do I enable this?

Comment: Looking at the [implementation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.0.0/modules/core/src/logger.cpp#L74), on anything other than android, it just writes to standard streams with no means of overriding that. Could definitely use a patch. If you're fine with logging to streams and just want to change the log level, then `setLogLevel` seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I set the log level using that method but I'm not seeing anything. Are the logs shown in the console or do I need to setup a file or something else to capture them?

Comment: I think perhaps I need a debug build of OpenCV to get this.

Comment: If it's logging, it should go to console. | See [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.0.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/utils/logger.hpp#L54) -- looks like you can control it with `CV_LOG_STRIP_LEVEL`, and have logging even in non-debug build.

Answer (score 14):

First include:

```
#include <opencv2/core/utils/logger.hpp>
```

Then in the code, do this as one of the first calls:

```
cv::utils::logging::setLogLevel(cv::utils::logging::LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE);
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. I also came across the other parameters that can be provided to `setLogLevel` [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/db0/namespacecv_1_1utils_1_1logging.html). For example: `cv::utils::logging::LOG_LEVEL_SILENT`.

Answer (score 11):

OpenCV uses environment variables to enable logging. In Bash:

```sh
export OPENCV_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG
export OPENCV_VIDEOIO_DEBUG=1
```

Comment: This is the best answer - simpler and additionally this will also catch logging from
CV_CAPTURE_LOG_DEBUG